# If [something] be

Tags: meaning-in-context, tense

In a [math book](https://calculusmadeeasy.org/14.html), an assumption is introduced using "if be":

> **if *y* be** the original capital, and the yearly interest is *y/n*, then, at the end of *n* years, his property will be [...]

Is the tense here the infinitive? What does "if it be" add to "if it is"?

This structure is also found in [Leonard Cohen's song](https://mojim.com/usy105191x19x35.htm) *If It Be Your Will*:

> **If it be** your will, that I speak no more
> And my voice be still, as it was before
> I will speak no more, I shall abide until
> I am spoken for, if it be your will

and in [Shakespeare](http://shakespeare.mit.edu/hamlet/hamlet.5.2.html):

> **If it be** now, 'tis not to come; **if it be** not to come, it will be now; **if it be** not now, yet it will come

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “be” is a subjunctive and can be equated in meaning to “is.” Modern American English has virtually eliminated the subjunctive. This text appears to be old and does not consistently use the subjunctive.

The subjunctive was used to indicate conditions that were uncertain or contrary to fact.

> If thou be’st born to see strange sights, things invisible to see

Comment: _Calculus Made Easy_ was published in 1910.

Comment: It's still occasionally used in math and other formal logic systems.  But a different subjunctive tense is still frequently used in common English: "*If I were there now, I would …*". And as with the other tense, it is used for hypothetical situations, where the speaker is not claiming that the condition is true.  Compare with "*If I was there last night, I wouldn't …*", where the speaker is claiming that the condition is definitely false.

Comment: As the assumption is stated in the book, yes it is associated with a context of uncertainty, which I didn't see (*If it had been only 2 per cent., he would have had to hoard for 50 years...*).

Comment: @mins Well, the whole point of a pronumeral such as y is to indicate that the value is unknown. But I agree with your common sense. Notice that “if y be capital and y/n is interest” is inconsistent.